# Alternatives to using drop down list in my asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I usually use drop down lists in many scenarios, such as selecting predefined types, parent record, etc.

But currently I am working on a system where a drop down list might have more than 200 records . and I want users to see more info about each record to be able to choose. So drop downs might not be user-friendly and usable in my case.

So what are other components or packages I can use with asp.net mvc , something like displaying a dialog box which allow users to search , filter , view more details about the record before selecting it?
BR

Comment: i think this is more of a usability question than programming question.

Comment: you can use jQuery autocomplete with custom data and display option http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) in these scenarios before with good results. It allows you to see the whole list if you need to (just like a regular dropdown) and it also gives you a way to filter the list if you know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using autocomplete; http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ this would solve the problem.

Comment: Autocomplate is good , but what if the user do not remember how to spell the word , or even he do not have any idea about the available options as in my case..

Comment: I would use select2, like Ragesh suggested if that was the case.